# Oracle EBS R12 - Release Hold Reason backend table

Tags: oracle, oracle-apps

When ever we release a hold in Oracle apps, We give a 'Reaason' for that.
could you please help me , in which table its stored.
and one more once we give the reason and click 'Apply' , which event would raise .

Please help

Comment: select release_reason_code,release_comment from OE_HOLD_RELEASES will give the answer.

Comment: Work order or invoice holds?

Answer (score 0):

select release_reason_code,release_comment from OE_HOLD_RELEASES a